# [Firebase Messaging]: Background Message Handler method not called when the app in background?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I-am developing an app for pushing notifications using FCM, when the app in background or terminated and receiving new notification i need to save the data of this notification local in (SQLITE), without click on the notification or re-open the app again, the notification not read in the app unless clicked. Any suggestions?

This my NotificationHandler.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:eshaar/model/message.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:eshaar/model/database_helper.dart';


FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  print("onBackgroundMessage: $message");
  //_showBigPictureNotification(message);
  return Future<void>.value();
}


Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {

}

class NotificationHandler {
  FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging();
  StreamSubscription iosSubscription;
  DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();
  static final NotificationHandler _singleton =
  new NotificationHandler._internal();

  factory NotificationHandler() {
    return _singleton;
  }
  NotificationHandler._internal();

  initializeFcmNotification() async {
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      iosSubscription = _fcm.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((data) {
        // save the token  OR subscribe to a topic here
      });

      _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings());
    } else {
      _saveDeviceToken();
    }

    _fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("---------------------On Message--------------------");
        displayNotification(message['data']['title'],message['data']['body']);
        _saveNotificationToLocal(message);
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isIOS ? null : myBackgroundMessageHandler ,
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("---------------------On Lunch--------------------");
        _saveNotificationToLocal(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("---------------------On Resume--------------------");
        _saveNotificationToLocal(message);
      },
    );
  }

  _saveNotificationToLocal(Map<String, dynamic> message){
    String sender_id = message['data']['sender_id'];
    String message_id = message['data']['message_id'];
    String title = message['data']['title'];
    String body = message['data']['body'];
    String del_time  = getCurrentDateTime();
    Messages msg = new Messages(sender_id,message_id,title,body,del_time);
    db.saveMessages(msg);

  }

 String getCurrentDateTime(){
   var now = new DateTime.now();
   var formatter = new DateFormat('MMM d yy h:mm a');
   String formatted = formatter.format(now);
   return formatted;
  }

  /// Get the token, save it to the database for current user
  _saveDeviceToken() async {
    String fcmToken = await _fcm.getToken();
  }


  Future<void> onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
      int id, String title, String body, String payload) async {
    // display a dialog with the notification details, tap ok to go to another page
  }

  void displayNotification(String title,String body) async{
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
        importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High, ticker: 'ticker');
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, '$title', '$body', platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'item x');
  }
}
```

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ot.eshaar.eshaar">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />



    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="eshaar"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />


            <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.android.channel_id"
                    android:value="mmne" />

            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />


    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Flutter doctor -v**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226, locale
    en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at /Users/mahmoudabdelaziz/Desktop/flutter
    • Framework revision 68587a0916 (3 months ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mahmoudabdelaziz/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling
      support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.0, Build version 11A420a
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.3.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 31.3.4
    • Dart plugin version 183.5153.38

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API
      28) (emulator)
```

Answer (score 19):

In my case, FCM `onBackgroundMessage` is triggered when only there is no notification on the payload. if there a notification on the payload what it does is it sends shows you notification on the system tray.

But if you want to do some compilation on the data sent then remove the **notification** on the payload and send **data** only.

```
{
  "to" : "Place the token of the test device here",
  "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
  "priority": "high",
  "data" : {
     "type" : "anything",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
     "key_1" : "Value for key_2"
  }

}
```

**UPDATED 2021**

Make sure to add `content_available` on the notification this worked for me now. I am using `firebase_messaging` prereplase. On this release they have enabled background handler out of the box.
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/versions/8.0.0-dev.14

```
{  
  "data":{  
    "title":"mytitle",
    "body":"mybody",
    "url":"myurl"
  },
 "notification":{  
    "title":"mytitle",
    "body":"mybody",
    "content_available": true
  },
  "to":"/topics/topic"
  "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
}
```

Comment: this really works. BUT fcm dont support data when app is completly terminated.

Comment: In your scenario, you need both notification and data. Notification is processed by the onBackgroundMessage handler and data is processed by the onMessage. Priority high is also important as specified.

Comment: I was sending the notification from a Java server. In my case, removing the notification from the message resolved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

It's late but still I'll respond for others to be helpful.

The issue here isn't with the handling but with type of message you are sending from the Firebase console.
`onBackgroundMessage` callBack is called only if the message is a data message or a notification message with a data payload.

And make sure your message also have `click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'` added.

And there as well is some issue with generating messages from Firebase console, so try to generate messages directly from your server.
For more details please checkout this [thread](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/199#issuecomment-536435481).

---

Comment: I tried send a notification via firebase console but not a test message, a fully message with key value data, but not working too... Seens that not trigering my background handler

Comment: Try sending a message to a specific device using device fcm token.

Comment: Yep, thanks, I got it when send a notification with data only,

Comment: Great it solved ur problem and don't forget to upvote the answer, so that others can find the solution easily.

Comment: It's worked. click-action was missed. Thank you lot

Answer (score 5):

please make sure that you have added click_action property while sending the notification.
make sure its value matches with the one you have provided in the android intent.

```
{
notification: {
    title: 'Title',
    body: 'Body',
    click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

In myBackgroundMessageHandler you need to call that function to save the notification to your local storage.

For example

```
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  print("onBackgroundMessage: $message");
  //_showBigPictureNotification(message);
    NotificationHandler()._saveNotificationToLocal(message);
  return Future<void>.value();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it still not working while app in background and not save the data unless clicking on the notification. Also, the function does not print the sentence.

Comment: This is how i have mine structured.

Future<dynamic> _myBackgroundMessageHandler(
    Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  if (message.containsKey('data')) {
    // Handle data message
    final dynamic data = message['data'];
    print(data);
    myAppState().processFCMessageEvent(data);
  }
}

Comment: Must also make sure you arent sending a notification if you intend on using backgroundmessage

Comment: This helped me out a lot have a look  at this link 

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/199

and look for the comment written by mobileink

Answer (score 0):

With postman send this and  "content_available": true trigger _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler

```
{
    "to": "_Token",
   "notification": {
        "title": "Title",
        "body": "body body body"
    },"data": {
      "title": "Title",
      "message": "body body body"

   },
   "apns": {
       "headers": {
           "apns-priority": "5"
       }
   },
   "priority": "high",
      "content_available": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line at the top of your background handler message.
@pragma('vm:entry-point')

Comment: This is needed only for the tree shake not to ignore the background handler method when the app is built for the release mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use this format

```
{
  "data": {
    "message": "YOUR MSG",
    "title": "TITLE"
  },
  "content_available": true,
  "priority": "high",
  "to": "DEVICE TOKEN"
}
```