# How to show a notification badge on the app icon using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm using FCM to push notifications in a flutter app.

I've tried a lot of things and codes to show a badge (red dot) on top of the app icon when a new notification arrives and the app is closed or in background.

What should I do to get a badge app icon in flutter ?

Answer (score 32):

Late answer but, on your question i think you want to add count to the app icon just like the image below.

[image: Notification badge on ios]

So for this issue you can use [flutter_app_badger](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_badger). Using this package you can add count to your app icon.

To use **flutter_app_badger** with **FCM** you can use this

```
 _firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage: $message");
    //Here you can add the count when you get a notification you can increase the number by one
    FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(1);
  },
  onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
    //Here you can remove the badge you created when it's launched
    FlutterAppBadger.removeBadge();
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");
  },
);
```

Then you can also add it to the background notification handler

```
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
   //Here you can add 
   FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(1);

   ...
   // Or do other work.
}
```

Remember, On ios background handler is triggered when only there is no notification on the payload.
You can read my more about this issue on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61646328/9949983).

Also, you can add a condition to check if the phone supports the badge or not using

```
bool res = await FlutterAppBadger.isAppBadgeSupported();
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this package, but I am still a bit confused how it works. Is your first code section only in the dart files? Is nothing needed in the node.js function that triggers the FCM notification? Also what if you have different PN functions and you want one to ```updateBadgeCount``` but the other not to?

Comment: Hey @MrHarvey, This package doesn't need cloud functions to be triggered. So what I did is whenever I receive a notification(FCM) I use this package to update the count.

Yes, the first code section is a dart file, that how u configure push notifications on dart applications. 

No, in my implementation u don't need Cloud functions

Comment: Hi most of my android devices is supported (i can see the badge on the other app) but it doesn't show up can you explain why. IOS work perfectly

Comment: @Nobody Hey,

I really can't explain why. at the point in time where I used this package, it worked perfectly for both platforms. Sorry, I couldn't be much of help.

Comment: it is not working on realme devices.

Comment: It doesn’t work on some of the android device… any other possible solution for this .. pls update ..

Comment: @GAGANSINGH Sorry, I have only found this package that works. May create an issue on the package Github. They might help you there.

Answer (score 3):

Try this JSON Body, I got the badge count and the sound,
still trying to figure out why,
and how to clear it after read.

```json
{
    "notification": {
        "body": "This is an FCM notification message!",
        "title": "FCM Message",
        "sound": "alert.aiff"
    },
    "priority": "high",
    "data": {
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        "id": "1",
        "status": "done"
    },
    "apns": {
        "payload": {
            "aps": {
                "badge": 9
            },
            "messageID" : "ABCDEFGHIJ"
        }
    },
    "to": "<the token you want to push to>"
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This badge is supported in all devices? I think it is supported in samsung, htc and some others.

Comment: My test devices are OPPO, iPhone X and iPhone 13. Not sure if all devices. I think it supports almost all main brands. Including Samsung, vivo, oppo, xiaomi , etc.