# How to control the count of app icon badge when I get notifications?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, notifications

It's when the app terminated.

I barely know how to play Kotlin, and I'm developing it as a Flutter!

I'd appreciate it if you could explain it in detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show a notification badge on the app icon using flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61979970/how-to-show-a-notification-badge-on-the-app-icon-using-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preference for storing the count of notification for showing counts in your app. (https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences ).

For showing in device apps home page with notifications , you can connect flutter local notification plugin in your code.(https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)