# how to show notificatiion in badges like any other app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Flutter and FCM and Firestore for my project i need to show unread notification count above bell icon and if any user click on any notification then details of the notification
please help with any article video or the code
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [link description](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/275/badge-on-icon-widgets-flutter/)

[Refer here for example](https://medium.com/@ayushbherwani/notification-badge-in-flutter-c776a6194936)

[badges: ^2.0.3](https://pub.dev/packages/badges)

If you are using [awesome notifications](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/274/show-notification-counter-badge-on-app-icon-flutter/) don't forget to add channelShowBadge: true on NotificationChannel(), so that the counter will be shown on the app icon.

```
void main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

   AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
     'resource://drawable/notification_icon', 
     [            // notification icon 
        NotificationChannel(
            channelGroupKey: 'basic_test',
            channelKey: 'basic',
            channelName: 'Basic notifications',
            channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
            channelShowBadge: true, //make it true, to show notifications counter
        ),

     ]
  );
   
  runApp(MyApp()); //run your app.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer on a similar issue "How to show a notification badge on the app icon using flutter?"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65701373/1275796