# How can i show notification count on app icon in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile, push-notification, notifications

In android devices, its working as expected by default i guess. But in iOS devices its not working like that. I search a lot and i found a package named : [flutter_app_badger](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_badger)

I using Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) for notifications. Notifications working well as expected. And i incrementing badge count with notifications. Inside app its working as expected. But when its in background or terminated its not increment count in badge. How can i solve it ? Its my codes for show notifications and increment badge.

```
Future<void> onBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
 
  LocalNotificationService.display(message);
}

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(onBackgroundMessageHandler);  //Inside

 FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage? message) async {
      if (message != null) {
        LocalNotificationService.display(message);
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) async {
      inspect(message);
      if (message.notification != null) {
        log("tıkladı");
      }
      LocalNotificationService.display(message);
    });

    //App is not terminatd but its in background
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      LocalNotificationService.display(message);
    });
```

That Display method is showing notification and also increment badge like :

```
if (await FlutterAppBadger.isAppBadgeSupported()) {
        final countCache = await 
        UserSecureStorage.getField("notificationBadgeCount"); 
        final int count = int.parse(countCache ?? "0") + 1;
        await UserSecureStorage.setField("notificationBadgeCount", count.toString());
        await FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(count);
      }
```

But its not increment in background or terminated as i said. How can i solve this issue ? Thanks for responses.

Comment: This may help you https://github.com/g123k/flutter_app_badger/issues/58

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani thanks for response. But i check it. Tried all but still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the problem you are facing before. It is not related to FCM or flutter_app_badger, it is related to notification body that is sent to FCM. You should update/modify your notification body just like the REST sample below:

```
    {
   "message":{
      "token":"XXXXXXXXX",
      "data":{},
      "notification":{
        "title":"FCM Message",
        "body":"This is an FCM notification message!"
      },
      "apns":{
        "payload": {
            "aps": {
                "sound": "default",
                "content-available": 1
            }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

The important part is apns part:

```
"apns":{
        "payload": {
            "aps": {
                "sound": "default",
                "content-available": 1
            }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show notification count in the app tray.

Find the below post. There is detailed explanation given:

[How to show a notification badge on the app icon using flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61979970/how-to-show-a-notification-badge-on-the-app-icon-using-flutter)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35146564)